# React Flow Chart : Automatic Layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

There are a few options available to create an automatic layout using react flow chart.
(chart has been created using `npm package react-flow-chart`)

I have tried the 2 mentioned below:

1. npm package `react-flow-chart` provides `smartRouting` config option
2. npm package `dagre`,

Both of these options work properly when I use it for nodes having same height.
In my chart, I may have nodes with different widths and different heights.

How can I make sure that automatic layout does not overlap nodes ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave this as a comment but don't have permissions, so need to leave it as an answer.

In the [layouting example on the site](https://reactflow.dev/examples/layouting/), it has a code snippet with a comment on how to do this:

```
const dagreGraph = new dagre.graphlib.Graph();
dagreGraph.setDefaultEdgeLabel(() => ({}));

// In order to keep this example simple the node width and height are hardcoded.
// In a real world app you would use the correct width and height values of
// const nodes = useStoreState(state => state.nodes) and then node.__rf.width, node.__rf.height

const nodeWidth = 172;
const nodeHeight = 36;

const getLayoutedElements = (elements, direction = 'TB') => {
  ...
};
```